# Dealing with user holding key down in JavaScript EventListener

Tags: javascript

So I am making a simple javascript game and I am using the spacebar to shoot missles.

Here is where I have problems:

```
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

        function keyDownHandler(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 39){
                rightPressed = true;
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 37){
                leftPressed =true;
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 32){  //Keycode for space bar
                missleFired = true;
            }
        }

        function keyUpHandler(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 39){
                rightPressed = false;
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 37){
                leftPressed = false;
            }
        }
```

In my keyDownHandler, I am using it to catch when the user is moving the spaceship left and right, or when the user presses spacebar to shoot. Problem is, I only want the "missleFired" variable to be set to true once, initially when the bar is pressed. The way it is right now, the user can hold the spacebar down and shoot loads of missles, but I want only one missle to be shot from the time the spacebar is held down until it is released. How can I do this?

Comment: You don't show it, but this is in the context of a game loop, yeah? Can you just set `missleFired = false` from the function that fires the missile, thereby forcing the user to release the spacebar and press it again to fire the next missile?

Comment: Where's the code that shoots the missiles?

Comment: I figured it out guys!! Check my answer below if you are interested as to what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

I did this: the missileFired block relies on the item in the array to be the string 'one' in order to process further. Using oneTime.shift(), it removes the item in the array and mutates it

```
const oneTime = ['one'];

function keyDownHandler(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37){
        leftPressed =true;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 32){  //Keycode for space bar
      if (e.keyCode == 32 && oneTime[0] !== 'one) {
        oneTime.shift(); // will remove the string 'one' out of the array for good. this code will not execute again
        missleFired = true;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured this out a minute ago and I posted my answer below. Which way is a better way to approach this?

Comment: Not my answer. Sorry I misunderstood the question, I thought you requested for a solution to only use missileFired once throughout the entire script/app

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
        var keys = [];
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

        function keyDownHandler(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 39){
                rightPressed = true;
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 37){
                leftPressed =true;
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 32){
                if(keys[e.keyCode]){
                    missleFired = false;
                }
                else{
                    missleFired = true;
                    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        function keyUpHandler(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 39){
                rightPressed = false;
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 37){
                leftPressed =false;
            }
            else if(e.keyCode == 32){
                keys[e.keyCode] = false;
            }
        }
```

I made a seperate array to hold whether or not certain keys are pressed and has a boolean property I can check when the keyDownHandler is called.